# How to test a condition on existing dataframe and put the results on a new column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

```
      ID   Open  Close     SMA        EMA
30  UNITY  11.50  11.53  12.576  12.715570
31  UNITY  11.44  11.34  12.399  12.626823
32  UNITY  11.26  11.74  12.273  12.569609
33  UNITY  11.72  11.61  12.150  12.507699
34  UNITY  11.51  11.43  11.994  12.438170
35  UNITY  11.85  11.17  11.844  12.356352
```

I want to test the following code

```
df[(df.SMA >= df.EMA) & 
    (((df.Open <= df.SMA) & (df.Close >= df.EMA)) 
        | ((df.Close >= df.EMA) & (df.Open <= df.EMA)) 
        | ((df.Open >= df.SMA) & (df.Close <= df.SMA)))]
```

on my dataframe and create a new column "TAZ" which, for each row, reflects '100' if the condition is met otherwise '0'.

Although the code works as per my requirements i am unable to put the result on a separate column. Little help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) like this:

```
# filter condition
cond = (df.SMA >= df.EMA) & (((df.Open <= df.SMA) & (df.Close >= df.EMA)) | ((df.Close >= df.EMA) & (df.Open <= df.EMA)) | ((df.Open >= df.SMA) & (df.Close <= df.SMA)))

df['TAZ'] = np.where(cond, 100, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a new column `TAZ` with the output of your code. By multiplying the result by 100 you will get 100 if the condition is met, otherwise it will be 0. If you'd like it as as string you can cast it using `astype()`

```
df['TAZ'] = ((df.SMA >= df.EMA) & (((df.Open <= df.SMA) & (df.Close >= df.EMA)) | ((df.Close >= df.EMA) & (df.Open <= df.EMA)) | ((df.Open >= df.SMA) & (df.Close <= df.SMA)))) * 100
```